# Unable to delete Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage-delete

I'm currently encountering an issue while attempting to delete an Azure storage account via the cli

```
az storage account delete --ids /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/foo-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/foostorageaccount --yes
```

The error message I receive is,
`(StorageAccountInCreating) Cannot delete the storage account while it is being created. Please retry after the storage account is fully created. Code: StorageAccountInCreating Message: Cannot delete the storage account while it is being created. Please retry after the storage account is fully created.`

And it's been this way for about 2-days now.

I've tried deleting the resource group as it's only for test project, but I get the same error.

Has anyone encountered and resolved this before?

Comment: can you check the provision status  ? `az storage account show --ids /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/foo-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/foostorageaccount --query provisioningState`

Comment: The provisioning state says `"Creating"`

Comment: Have you already tried to delete it via RestAPI?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/delete?tabs=HTTP

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you've encountered a rare state where a Storage Account creation process got stuck and left the resource in a "Creating" state, which prevents further actions like deletion or any other action for that matter.

Unfortunately, once a resource gets stuck in this state, there's very little that can be done with out involving the support team, I believe the only way forward to have this removed is to raise a support ticket with Azure.  In the interim you can always create a new storage account with a different name and new resource group etc.

Comment: I've reached out to Azure, but as I'm on the Basic support plan, it doesn't look like there's anything they can do for me, and the only solution is to delete the entire subscription, which I think is a bit of an overkill, but I suppose that's what you get for being on a Basic plan.

Comment: @Metro , raising a ticket on this is also important from the point that this seems to be a bug and they will do more efforts fix the bug globally if there are more tickets piling up on the same bug.